# pg_restore to create database before loading it?

Tags: postgresql

I understand that pg_restore needs to connect to a database before it can start the restore process, is there anyway pg_restore can use the "postgres" database to create another database?

I have the following command

```
pg_restore -h "192.168.1.212" -p 5432 -U mysuperusername -C -d bp bp.custom
```

when I run the command I get the following message

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "bp" failed: FATAL:
>   database "bp" does not exist

Is there anyway for pg_restore to create the "bp" database without me having to create it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `-d postgres` on the command line.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) for the `-C` option. The database to be restored is automatically take from the backup file

> When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is restored **into the database name that appears in the archive**.

```
pg_restore -h "192.168.1.212" -p 5432 -U mysuperusername -C -d postgres bp.custom
```

Comment: I tried it with `pg_restore -h "192.168.1.212" -p 5432 -U mysuperusername -d postgres -C bp bp.custom` and I get the following message `pg_restore: too many command-line arguments (first is "bp.custom")`

Comment: @Arya: well in the part `-C bp bp.custom` the first `bp` is wrong

Comment: but bp is the name of the database I want created. bp.custom is the backup file

Comment: You do **not** need to specify the database to be created because that information is stored in the backup

Comment: I understand now, is there anyway to have pg_restore to create the user that was used with the database? for example, for my "bp" database was used by the user "bp" anyway to create the user with pg_restore?

Comment: let us say you had a user called myuser and a database called mydb which belonged to myuser. can you pg_restore by creating mydb and a myuser and assigning mydb to myuser all in one step? while restoring?